# How to rename label within a metric in Prometheus

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I have a query:

```
node_systemd_unit_state{instance="server-01",job="node-exporters",name="kubelet.service",state="active"} 1
```

I want the label `name` being renamed (or replaced) to `unit_name` ONLY within the `node_systemd_unit_state` metric. So, desired result is:

```
node_systemd_unit_state{instance="server-01",job="node-exporters",unit_name="kubelet.service",state="active"} 1
```

There are many other metrics with a label name `name` in the `node-exporters` job. That's why I can't use relabel config across the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have more than one source label, so:

```
- source_labels: [__name__, name]
  regex: "node_systemd_unit_state;(.+)"
  target_label: unit_name
```

If the label name isn't matching up with other metrics/exporters, you should file a bug with them. Relabelling like this should only be a temporary solution while a proper fix is being pursued.

Comment: great! But in this case I'll always have two labels: `name` and `unit_name` which values is the same every time. I'd like to avoid this kind of duplication.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to do this, apart from temporarily storing the value of `name` in a `__tmp_name` label, dropping it from all metrics and then adding it back to all metrics except `node_systemd_unit_state`. But writing the regex to match everything but `node_systemd_unit_state` will be a PITA and the whole process will probably not be all that efficient.

Answer (score 35):

you can use the label_replace function in promQL, but it also add the label, don't replace it

```
label_replace(
  <vector_expr>, "<desired_label>", "$1", "<existing_label>", "(.+)"
)

label_replace(
node_systemd_unit_state{instance="server-01",job="node-exporters",name="kubelet.service",state="active"},
"unit_name","$1","name", "(.+)"
)
```

So, to avoid the repetition you can add:

```
sum(label_replace(
    node_systemd_unit_state{instance="server-01",job="node-exporters",name="kubelet.service",state="active"},
    "unit_name","$1","name", "(.+)"
    )
)by(unit_name)
```

Comment: this is the method without doing any configuration change!

Comment: What if I want to change the actual name of the metric (e.g. __name__) rather than a regular label.

Answer (score 18):

I got tired of all the fragmented documentation and I feel I provided a better answer in this post here:
https://medium.com/@texasdave2/replace-and-remove-a-label-in-a-prometheus-query-9500faa302f0

**Replace is not a true REPLACE**

Your goal is to simply replace the old label name “old_job_id” with a new label name “new_task_id”. Prometheus label_replace will really “add” the new label name. It will preserve the old label name as well… So, that could be a problem, it’s not a true “replace in place”.

So if you want to “add” your new label name and “remove” the old label name, you need to do this:

```
sum without (old_job_id) (label_replace(metric, "new_task_id", "$1", "old_job_id", "(.*)"))
```

Here’s how this reads:

- sum without (old_job_id) will remove the old label name from the
  query output
- metric is your metric, like “node_filesystem_avail_bytes”
- “new_task_id” is where you would put your new label name
- “$1” is regex for using the string in new label name, don’t change
  this
- “old_job_id” is where you’ll put your old label, the one you want to
  get rid of (.*……. that mess is regex that will replace the whole
  label name

Answer (score 2):

Prometheus allows renaming labels in the following places:

- During metric scrape. In this case you need to add the following [relabeling rules](https://valyala.medium.com/how-to-use-relabeling-in-prometheus-and-victoriametrics-8b90fc22c4b2) into `metric_relabel_configs` section at the corresponding [scrape_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config):

```yaml
metric_relabel_configs:
- source_labels: [__name__, name]
  regex: "node_systemd_unit_state;(.+)"
  target_label: unit_name
- source_labels: [__name__, name]
  regex: "node_systemd_unit_state;(.+)"
  target_label: name
  replacement: ""
```

The first rule copies `name` label value into `unit_name` label for metrics with `node_systemd_unit_state` name. The second rule sets `name` label value to an empty string (e.g. deletes the `name` label) for metrics with `node_systemd_unit_state` name.

- During querying via [label_join()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_join) function:

```
label_join(
  label_join(node_systemd_unit_state, "unit_name", "", "name"),
  "name", "", "non_existing_label"
)
```

The inner `label_join()` copies `name` label into `unit_name` label. The outer `label_join()` substitutes the original `name` label with an empty string (e.g. remove the `name` label).

As you can see, `label_join()` isn't the best function for label renaming. The [label_replace()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) isn't the best function for label renaming too. While Prometheus doesn't provide better solutions for label renaming, such solution exist in Prometheus-like systems such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) (I'm the author of this system). It provides [label_move()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_move) function:

```
label_move(node_systemd_unit_state, "name", "unit_name")
```

Additionally, VictoriaMetrics provides `if` option for conditional relabeling rules. For example, the following relabeling rules are equivalent to the rules above, but are easier to understand and maintain:

```yaml
metric_relabel_configs:
- if: 'node_systemd_unit_state{name!=""}'
  source_labels: [name]
  target_label: unit_name
- if: 'node_systemd_unit_state{name!=""}'
  target_label: name
  replacement: ""
```

Comment: You should have disclaimed that you are the CTO of VictoriaMetrics.

Answer (score 0):

https://demo.promlens.com/?q=label_replace(up%2C%20%22hostname%22%2C%20%22%241%22%2C%20%22instance%22%2C%20%22(.%2B)%3A(%5C%5Cd%2B)%22)

Assume you have metric namely `up`

```
up{instance="cadvisor:8080", job="cadvisor"}    
up{instance="demo-service-0:10000", job="demo"} 
up{instance="demo-service-1:10001", job="demo"} 
up{instance="demo-service-2:10002", job="demo"} 
up{instance="docker-hub-exporter:9170", job="docker-hub-exporter"}  
up{instance="node-exporter:9100", job="node"}   
up{instance="prometheus:9090", job="prometheus"}
```

Now query 
`label_replace(up, "hostname", "$1", "instance", "(.+)-(.+)-(\\d+):(\\d+)")` 
will return with new label hostname with first match group ("$1").

```
up{instance="cadvisor:8080", job="cadvisor"}    
up{hostname="demo", instance="demo-service-0:10000", job="demo"}
up{hostname="demo", instance="demo-service-1:10001", job="demo"}
up{hostname="demo", instance="demo-service-2:10002", job="demo"}
up{instance="docker-hub-exporter:9170", job="docker-hub-exporter"}
up{instance="node-exporter:9100", job="node"}
up{instance="prometheus:9090", job="prometheus"}
```

Query 
`label_replace(up, "hostname", "$2", "instance", "(.+)-(.+)-(\\d+):(\\d+)")` 
will return with new label hostname with second match group ("$2") of the regEx.

```
up{instance="cadvisor:8080", job="cadvisor"}    
up{hostname="service", instance="demo-service-0:10000", job="demo"} 
up{hostname="service", instance="demo-service-1:10001", job="demo"} 
up{hostname="service", instance="demo-service-2:10002", job="demo"} 
up{instance="docker-hub-exporter:9170", job="docker-hub-exporter"}  
up{instance="node-exporter:9100", job="node"}   
up{instance="prometheus:9090", job="prometheus"}
```