# Add queries with different label in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

I have two queries:

```
max(pg_database_pg_database_size{instance=~"rds_db1"}) by (instance, kubernetes_namespace)
```

```
max(aws_rds_free_storage_space_average{dbinstance_identifier=~"rds_db1"}) by (dbinstance_identifier, kubernetes_namespace)
```

I want to add those queries together, but the name of the instance labels are different. How can I do it?

I am able to do it if I remove the labels:

```
max (aws_rds_free_storage_space_average{dbinstance_identifier=~"rds_db1"}) + max(pg_database_pg_database_size{instance=~"rds_db1"})
```

But I want one of the labels, either dbinstance_identifier or instance, and kubernetes_namespace, which is common to both queries.

Comment: You can use label_replace; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54833182/13963086

Comment: @k314159 It works without adding. With 

max (label_replace(aws_rds_free_storage_space_average{dbinstance_identifier=~"rds_db1"},"instance","$1","dbinstance_identifier", "(.+)")) by (instance, kubernetes_namespace)

The label gets replaced successfully. But when I try to do:

max (label_replace(aws_rds_free_storage_space_average{dbinstance_identifier=~"rds_db1"},"instance","$1","dbinstance_identifier", "(.+)")) by (instance, kubernetes_namespace)
+
max(pg_database_pg_database_size{instance=~"rds_db1"}) by (instance, kubernetes_namespace)

It shows empty query result.