# How can I remove a label and then rename another one to replace it?

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

I have two different metrics that I am trying to combine in a PromQL expression to write an alert. One of the metrics, say `is_up` represents if a node is up. The other metric `is_active` represents if something on that node is running.

Each of them have labels that can be used to compare them, but the labels are called different things on each. So on `is_up` we have `label_a="node_id"` and on `is_active` we have `label_b="node_id"` where the `node_ids` are the same.

If the label names were the same, e.g. `label`, I could write a query that looks like:

```
count(is_up) by (label) unless count(is_active) by (label)
```

But this isn't possible. I can't relabel it in a global config as there is already a label on `is_up` that is called `label_b` but it has a different format :/

So my current thinking is to (using PromQL, so at *evaluation* time) remove the `label_b` from `is_up` and rename the label `label_a` to `label_b`

I saw this answer previously about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60894489/16546473 but I'm not sure that it applies to me as it's just talking about renaming a label, but I need to

1. remove `label_b` from `is_up`, then
2. rename `label_a` in `is_up` to `label_b` so that it can be directly compared to `label_b` in `is_active`

Let me know if this makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed it like this:

```
sum without (label_a) (label_replace(sum(is_up) without (label_b), "label_b", "$1", "label_a", "(.*)"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The full solution is the following:

```
count(is_up) by (label_a)
  unless on (label_a)
label_replace(
  count(is_active) by (label_b),
  "label_a",
  "$1",
  "label_b",
  "(.*)"
)
```

It works in the following way:

1. The `count(is_up) by (label_a)` counts `is_up` series grouped by `label_a`. See [docs for count() aggregate function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count).
2. The `count(is_active) by (label_b)` counts `is_active` series grouped by `label_b`.
3. The `label_replace(...)` copies the `label_a` value to `label_b` for all the series returned at step 2. Note that the time series now have two identical labels - `label_a` and `label_b`. See [label_replace() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace).
4. The `unless on (label_a)` instructs returning series from step 1 only if there are no matching series from step 3 with the given `label_a` value. See [docs for unless operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) and [docs for on() modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching).